# python flask simple resetful api not just add 1 record user in sqlite database

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

i create a simple resetful api with flask and work corrent , but after add 1 record user details , don't add next user or second user in database and give error 500.

my server is: centos 7

python: 3.7.5

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_marshmallow import Marshmallow
import os

app = Flask(__name__)
basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///' + os.path.join(basedir, 'crud.sqlite')
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
ma = Marshmallow(app)


class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(150), unique=True)
    userid = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True)
    product = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=True)
    licenses = db.Column(db.String(1000), unique=True)

    def __init__(self, username, userid , product , licenses):
        self.username = username
        self.userid = userid
        self.product = product
        self.licenses = licenses


class UserSchema(ma.Schema):
    class Meta:
        # Fields to expose
        fields = ('username', 'userid', 'product', 'licenses')


user_schema = UserSchema()
users_schema = UserSchema(many=True)

'''
Message list:
- 1x0001 = user created
- 1x0002 = user deleted
- 1x0003 = user updated
- 0x0000 = Error not found customer
- 0x0001 = Error can't add customer
- 0x0003 = Error not found customer for delete
- 0x0004 = Error can't update customer
product list:
- 2x0001 = MoeinWeb
- 2x0002 = MoeinBackup
'''

# endpoint to create new user
@app.route("/api/LicenseService/newcustomer", methods=["POST"])
def add_user():
    try:
        data = request.get_json()
        new_user = User(username=data['username'], userid=data['userid'], product=data['product'], licenses=data['licenses'])
        db.session.add(new_user)
        db.session.commit()
        return jsonify({'Message': '1x0001'})
    except:
        return jsonify({'Message': '0x0001'})


# endpoint to get user detail by id
@app.route("/api/LicenseService/customer/<userid>", methods=["GET"])
def user_detail(userid):
    user = User.query.filter_by(userid=userid).first()
    try:
        user_data = {}
        user_data['username'] = user.username
        user_data['userid'] = user.userid
        user_data['product'] = user.product
        user_data['licenses'] = user.licenses
        return jsonify(user_data)
    except:
        return jsonify({'Message': '0x0000'})


# endpoint to update user
@app.route("/api/LicenseService/customer/<userid>", methods=["PUT"])
def user_update(userid):
    try:
        user = User.query.filter_by(userid=userid).first()
        username = request.json['username']
        userid = request.json['userid']
        product = request.json['product']
        licenses = request.json['licenses']
        user.username = username
        user.userid = userid
        user.product = product
        user.licenses = licenses
        db.session.commit()
        return jsonify({'Message': '1x0003'})
    except:
        return jsonify({'Message': '0x0004'})


# endpoint to delete user
@app.route("/api/LicenseService/customer/<userid>", methods=["DELETE"])
def user_delete(userid):
    try:
        user = User.query.filter_by(userid=userid).first()
        db.session.delete(user)
        db.session.commit()
        return jsonify({'Message': '1x0002'})
    except:
        return jsonify({'Message': '0x0003'})


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0',port=7273)
```

just record 1 can update , delete and show with userid , but can't create record 2 on database ,

> add_user()

Comment: How does userid get set in the form?

Comment: 1. You delete any information you can get about errors by catching any exception. That is a bad idea. 2. You say that "product" is unique; that means that if a product is bought by 1 customer, no other can buy it anymore. Seems wrong.

Comment: I guess with resetful you mean RESTful? Perhaps you edit the question?

Comment: Can you please show the error also?

Comment: Your example code works for me.  I just had to add a call to `db.create_all()` after the model definition.  There are many unique constraints in the table.  As long as I adhered to the constraints I could create multiple users.